# Create DTO by joining EF entity with another object in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have an Entity Framework entity

```
public class Entiy 
{
    public string EntityProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string EntityProperty2 { get; set; }
    public string EntityProperty3 { get; set; }
    public Guid? SomeId { get; set; }
}
```

And also an OtherObject and a DTO which contains properties that'd be equal to the other classes.

```
public class OtherObject
{
    public string OtherObjectProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string OtherObjectProperty2 { get; set; }
    public string OtherObjectProperty3 { get; set; }
    public Guid SomeId { get; set; }
}

public class DTO
{
    public string EntityProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string EntityProperty2 { get; set; }
    public string EntityProperty3 { get; set; }
    public string OtherObjectProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string OtherObjectProperty2 { get; set; }
    public string OtherObjectProperty3 { get; set; }
}
```

In my service class I get an IQueryable of my entities and I send in an argument which contains an enumerable of OtherObject. It works fine when I just want to create DTOs using the Entities properties.

```
public IEnumerable<DTO> GetDtos(IEnumerable<OtherObject> otherObjects) 
{
    return _someRepository.GetAll()
        .Where(a => otherObjects.Select(b => b.SomeId).Contains(a.SomeId))
        .Select(d => new DTO()
            {
                EntityProperty1 = d.EntityProperty1
                EntityProperty2 = d.EntityProperty2 
                EntityProperty3 = d.EntityProperty3
            })
        .ToList();
}
```

However, I would also like to join in some properties from my OtherObject class. If I do the following

```
public IEnumerable<DTO> GetDtos(IEnumerable<OtherObject> otherObjects) 
{
    return _someRepository.GetAll()
        .Where(a => otherObjects.Select(b => b.SomeId).Contains(a.SomeId))
        .Select(d => new DTO()
            {
                EntityProperty1 = d.EntityProperty1
                EntityProperty2 = d.EntityProperty2 
                EntityProperty3 = d.EntityProperty3
                OtherObjectEntity1 = otherObjects.FirstOrDefault(a => a.SomeId == d.SomeId).OtherObjectEntity1
            })
        .ToList();
}
```

I get the following error: "Unable to create a constant value of type XXX. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context"

Comment: How is your `DTO` class defined?

Comment: @TobiasJohansson again what is `e.SomeId`? Could you not even read that question above?

Comment: It's a typo. It should say d.SomeId since it's coming from the entity class.

Comment: the important thing here is `e` - it's used the first time right in `e.SomeId`, you should update to show your actual code. Currently it does not even compile

Comment: I agree. I changed the e.SomeId to d.SomeId. Missed that in my previous edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a property from otherObject by adding another Select to the first query

```
public IEnumerable<DTO> GetDtos(IQueryable<OtherObject> otherObjects) 
{
   var ids = otherObjects.Select(x => x.SomeId);
   return _someRepository.GetAll()
          .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.SomeId)
          .ToList()
          .Select(x =>
                 new DTO()
                 {
                    EntityProperty1 = x.EntityProperty1,
                    EntityProperty2 = x.EntityProperty2, 
                    EntityProperty3 = x.EntityProperty3,
                    OtherObjectEntity1 = otherObjects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.SomeId == x.SomeId).OtherObjectEntity1
                 };
}
```

Also I extracted otherObjects' ids into local variable to optimize the query a little bit.

Comment: why the hell this answer was accepted? `otherObjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SomeId == item.SomeId)` will surely force EF to create a constant of type `OtherObject` which does not have any equivalent type in SQL, it surely throws exception. Using `let` will just help you make the query compile but once executed, the exception will still be thrown. We simply cannot solve the OP's problem ***easily***.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I rewrote the query using additional Select

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Join instead od Where ?
It would look something like this:

```
_someRepository.GetAll()
        .Join(otherObjects, a => a.SomeId, b => b.SomeId, (d, e) => new DTO
            {
                EntityProperty1 = d.EntityProperty1
                EntityProperty2 = d.EntityProperty2 
                EntityProperty3 = d.EntityProperty3
                OtherObjectEntity1 = e.OtherObjectEntity1
            })
        .ToList();
```

In my opinion it would be allso more efficient than your implementation.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the comments, I checked the query with database and it didn't work.
I decided to fix the query, if you would like to use Join :)

```
        var ids = otherObjects.Select(i => i.Id);

        // When
        var results = repository.GetAll()
            .Where(a => ids.Contains(a.Id))
            .ToList()
            .Join(otherObjects, a => a.Id, b => b.Id, (a, b) => new SimpleDto
            {
                Id = a.Id,
                Name = a.Name,
                Attribute = b.Attribute
            })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Neat implementation. However, I'm still getting the same error. "A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'xxx.OtherObject'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Comment: For Milosz answer to work, the otherObjects must be IQueryable instead of IEnumerable. The join and projection (the creation of DTO) must resolve to SQL generation, hence must use IQueryable on both repository and otherQbjects. If you replaced otherObjects with IQueryable and it still doesn't work, perhaps it's Entity Framework's limitation; with that said, try my first and second suggestion from my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33141963/create-dto-by-joining-ef-entity-with-another-object-in-linq/33142360#33142360)

Comment: I tried changing the parameter to an IQueryable but it still doesn't work. As far as I know, Guid and Guid? are not primitive types. Perhaps that's what entity framework is complaining about? I will try your solution next.

Comment: You cannot project to a DTO in a IQueryable expression because the SQL Expression Builder does not know how to interpret a DTO projection. You can only project to a Anonymous Object collection... In order to project out after wards (i.e. after the IQueryable has been enumerated) you can use the join or you can use AutoMapper

Comment: @CallumLinington: Could you elaborate? I'm not sure how I'd combat that.

Comment: There should be a bunch of stackoverflow posts on EntityFramework Joins and Automapper

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, is to do a ToList after the Where clause, then do DTO projection afterwards. Doing an early ToList would overselect all columns of the repository, which is bad for performance.

Another option, materialized the first three columns first..

```
var result = 
    someRepository.GetAll()
        .Where(a => otherObjects.Select(b => b.SomeId).Contains(a.SomeId))
        .Select(d => new DTO()
            {
                EntityProperty1 = d.EntityProperty1
                EntityProperty2 = d.EntityProperty2 
                EntityProperty3 = d.EntityProperty3
            }).
 .ToList()
```

..then re-project the DTO:

```
 result = result(d => 
          new DTO() {
              EntityProperty1 = d.EntityProperty1,
              EntityProperty2 = d.EntityProperty2,
              EntityProperty3 = d.EntityProperty3,
              OtherObjectEntity1 = otherObjects.FirstOrDefault(a => a.SomeId == e.SomeId).OtherObjectEntity1
          }
```

Yet another approach is to use IQueryable on IQueryable. That would generate subquery in SELECT statement.

```
public IEnumerable<DTO> GetDtos(IQueryable<OtherObject> otherObjects) 
{
    return _someRepository.GetAll()
        .Where(a => otherObjects.Select(b => b.SomeId).Contains(a.SomeId))
        .Select(d => new DTO()
            {
                EntityProperty1 = d.EntityProperty1
                EntityProperty2 = d.EntityProperty2 
                EntityProperty3 = d.EntityProperty3,
                OtherObjectEntity1 = otherObjects.FirstOrDefault(a => a.SomeId == e.SomeId).OtherObjectEntity1
            })
        .ToList();
}
```

---

Or use join (Milosz Wieczorek's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33141963/create-dto-by-joining-ef-entity-with-another-object-in-linq/33142232#33142232)), it's more efficient than subquery.

Comment: Yeah, I like Milosz answer because of its simplicity. However, I keep getting the same error using his solution.